# Can't connect to org.freedesktop.UDisks via DBus-Python

Tags: python, dbus

It's the first time I'm using DBus so please bear with me.
This is my code:

```
import gobject
import pprint
gobject.threads_init()

from dbus import glib
glib.init_threads()

import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()

remote_object = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", # Connection name
                               "/org/freedesktop/UDisks" # Object's path
                              )

print ("Introspection data:\n")
print remote_object.Introspect()
print remote_object.get_dbus_method("ListNames",dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus")
for item in remote_object.ListNames():
        print item
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UDisks was not provided by any .service files
```

From the [udisk-demon manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/udisks-daemon.8.html)

*udisks-daemon provides the org.freedesktop.UDisks service on the system message bus. **Users or administrators should never need to start this daemon as it will be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) whenever an application calls into the org.freedesktop.UDisks service.** See the udisks(7) man page for information on how to customize how udisks-daemon works.*

**EDIT:** So it was `SystemSession()` and not `SessionBus()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [DFeet](http://live.gnome.org/DFeet/) to check if this dbus object really exists.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, but I don't see the ListNames method you used, so I used EnumerateDevices.

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
udisks = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks")
udisks = dbus.Interface(udisks, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')
devices = udisks.get_dbus_method('EnumerateDevices')()
```